# How to run two functions asynchronously in JavaScript using Async/Await;

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple react pharmacy application in which I'm supposed to change remove all the medicines from a certain group and then delete the group.

I have the two functions created like this.

**1. changeMedicineGroupFunction**

```
  const changeMedicineGroup = (medicineId, groupIdToChangeTo) => {
    fetch(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ROOT_URL}/changeMedicineGroup/${medicineId}/${groupIdToChangeTo}`,
      {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((response) => console.log(response));
  };
```

**2.deleteGroupFunction.**

```
  const deleteGroup = () => {
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ROOT_URL}/deletegroup/${data.groupId}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((response) => console.log(response));
  };
```

then a final function is used to invoke the two functions above as follows

```
  const removeMedicinesFromGroup = async () => {
    let unSetGroupId = 24;
    groupMedicines.forEach((medicine) =>
      changeMedicineGroup(medicine.medicineId, unSetGroupId)
    );
    deleteGroup();
  };
```

**QUESTION** **How do I make my `removeMedicinesFromGroup()` function asynchronous in such a way that the `deleteGroup()` function is only invoked when the code above it is complete** i.e the `changing medicine Group` logic. I want to use async-await. This is crucial for my application because if I delete a group while it still has data I have like whole foreign key constraint errors I'm trying to avoid.

Please Help.

Comment: a) to use `async`/`await`, your `changeMedicineGroup` and `deleteGroup` functions must **`return`** the promises b) when using `async`/`await`, [you cannot use `.forEach()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572) for looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve that ,you have to some changes in your code.
Starting with
`changeMedicineGroupFunction` and `deleteGroup` that both should return a promise in order to await it in another function in your case `removeMedicinesFromGroup`.

Example of changeMedicineGroupFunction:

```
const changeMedicineGroup = (medicineId, groupIdToChangeTo) => {
    return fetch(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ROOT_URL}/changeMedicineGroup/${medicineId}/${groupIdToChangeTo}`,
      {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => res.text())

  };
```

then in removeMedicinesFromGroup :

```
const removeMedicinesFromGroup = async () => {
    let unSetGroupId = 24;
    for(const medicin of groupMedicines){
     await changeMedicineGroup(medicine.medicineId, unSetGroupId)
    }
    await deleteGroup();
// you can use await here or let deleteGroup as it is without the behaviour you want will be achieved.
  };
```

And i used regular for Loop instead of forEach to use await in it.
I found this now that has many answers about using `async/await` in for loop whether sequence or parallel.
[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

I hope it works for you.

Comment: You accidentally removed the `res.text()` from `changeMedicineGroup`, otherwise this is a good answer

Comment: Thanks @Zomitaka so what you are saying is that my function that i need to wait for must return a promise>

Comment: Exactly @AmohPrince and don't forget the other changes in `removeMedicinesFromGroup`. Yes @Bergi that's right i'll add it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `deleteGroup()` after the code above it has completed by preceding the code above with `await` keyword.

For example:

```
await doSomethingBefore();
await alsoDoThisBefore();
// deleteGroup() is only invoked after the two awaited calls have completed
deleteGroup();
```

Comment: Why are you not waiting for `deleteGroup()` itself?

Comment: Because the question was only about invoking it after something has happened. Obviously the same applies regardless of function name.

Answer (score 0):

changeMedicineGroup should return a promise for each medicine and use `Promise.all()` to check if all the required groups have been changed or not and post that remove the group.
In case if any of those fails the group won't be deleted .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all